Looker Studio - Using a google sheet with a query function as a source
Has anyone experienced any issues connecting their looker studio report to a google sheet containing a query function?
Initially, the report source was entirely based on the query function, and this would return no rows until manually refreshed within the studio report.
I changed this so that the source had 10 static rows (11 including the header row), and then added the query function onto the 12th row.
On report load, the 10 static rows of data from the sheet will load fine. The query function, which starts at row 12, will not provide data until the report is manually refreshed. I'm not sure what's causing this behaviour, and wondered if anyone has experienced similar? Query function used, for reference:
=query('Q27'!D12:G,"select *",0)

As you can see it's quite simple, take all data from the range specified, don't include the header.
Best wishes
Dave
